# Does this error (in R) mean I am missing a package?

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

The following is my code

```
filtered_toothgrowth <- ToothGrowth %>% 
  filter(dose==0.5) %>% 
  arrange(len)
```

The error I'm getting

```
Error in object.size(obj) : could not find function "object.size"
```

Could this be a package issue?

Comment: A restart of R or Rstudio might help. It's also possible that it is trying to apply those functions from a non-dplyr package. You could try making the calls explicit and see if that solves the issue (i.e., `dplyr::filter` and `dplyr::arrange`.

Comment: Are you running this on the console or in a script?

Comment: `object.size` is a base function in R, in the `utils` package.  Your R is either very, very old, or is seriously broken.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AndrewGB. Restarting helped. My code run. I also made sure that the dplyr package was loaded.

Comment: @r2evans, this time round I run the code on the console. I'd previously run it in script